# Chart.js Y Axis Wrong Step Count

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

My Y axis isn't lining up with the chart values. I'm not sure how to fix this issue using the options. I searched around but none of those answers solved the problem. The chart values that are wrong are:

> Red: **245** Orange: **337** Yellow: **461** Green: **776** Purple: 4331 (Correct because of max value being set)

```
var options = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        spanGaps: false,
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0.000001
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                 ticks : {
                    max : max_chart,  //This is the max dataset value  
                    min : 0,
                    stepSize: 500
                }

            }]
        },
    };
```

[image: Test Chart]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your full code. Your problem is not reproducible with just the chart options.

Comment: I just noticed that you've set `stacked: true`. Your values look correct in this case because each series considers 0 to be at the max value of the previous series. Remove `stacked: true` if you want each series to normalise to the 0 line.

Comment: Perfect! Can you post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `stacked: true`. Your values look correct in this case because each series considers 0 to be at the max value of the previous series.

Remove `stacked: true` if you want each series to normalise to the 0 line.